# How can I repair apt / dpkg?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt, dpkg

Apt keeps crashing when I try to run

```
apt-get upgrade

xxx@xxx:/root/# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cvs dovecot-common dovecot-pop3d language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
  language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base libgssapi-krb5-2
  libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libssl0.9.8 login openssl passwd
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/14.9MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,731kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `cvs' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 141611 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cvs 1:1.12.13-12ubuntu1 (using .../cvs_1%3a1.12.13-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement cvs ...
```

And it just hangs there :(, CTRL+C does nothing
I've drive killing dpkg and apt afterwards with

```
sudo killall -9 dpkg
sudo killall -9 apt-get
```

but dpkg remains running :(

I managed to kill all processes at one point and tried to remove cvs (thinking that was the problem but I had no luck).

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure debconf  and setting
the priority to medium  try that

Comment: use `kill -9 <pids>` to kill everyone and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

when you gt stuck in that situation background current process with CTRL+Z

that should give you shell again.

then do
`pgrep dpkg | xargs kill -9` # kill all processes matching string dpkg

`pgrep apt-get | xargs kill -9` # kill all processes matching string apt-get

`dpkg --purge cvs` # remove currently installed cvs package

`apt-get update` # update package lists from your apt repositories

`apt-get install cvs` # install cvs package from the updated repositories

Comment: xxx@xxx:~# dpkg --purge cvs
    dpkg: error processing cvs (--purge):
     Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
     reinstall it before attempting a removal.
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     cvs

Comment: try "aptitude reinstall cvs"

Comment: hmm I don't think cvs is the problem now. I managed to remove cvs with: "sudo apt-get --purge remove --force cvs" but after trying a apt-get upgrade. It stalled on "Unpacking replacement login ..."

Comment: Ah and those commands arn't killing my dpkg processes. Weird...

Comment: and finally: "xxx@xxx:~# ps -aef |grep dpkg" tells me: root     11983     1  0 Feb16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 25 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/cvs_1%3a1.12.13-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libparams-validate-perl_0.93-1_amd64.deb <snip lota crap>. Tried to kill it but I cant

Comment: if kill -9 11983 cant kill it I dont think anything but reboot will :/

Comment: Yep a reboot solved it. Found this: http://arstechnica.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=316926

Answer (score 1):

I'd first try to find out what the process is trying to do and why it might have gotten stuck there. This is most likely a problem that is somewhat independent from the missing list of files (which you've already solved by installing the exact same version of the package on top; dpkg will just generate a new file list from the new package then).

I think there may be something wrong with your file system, such as a loop of directory hardlinks or other inconsistency that confuses the kernel here; thus the first step for me in this situation would be to confirm this (e.g. by checking which kernel function the process is blocked in), and, if that is truly the case, to reboot and force a file system check.

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't look like a dpkg/apt error to me. Have a look at the output of `dmesg` and see if there's any underlying problem. Also, try `strace -fp <dpkg pid>` to see what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this bug myself - it's apparently known and actively worked on here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/624877